# In Flutter how can I sort integer values stored in strings

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

I have the numbers like

```
 ListData=[1.69K,1.32K,1.25K,1.23K,2,45,34]
```

I want output like

```
[2,34,45,1.25K,1.32K,1.69K]
```

I have used

```
ListData.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b))
```

But It wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
listData.sort((a, b){
    if(a.contains('K')){
      a = a.replaceAll('K','');
      a = double.parse(a) * 1000;
    }else{
      a = double.parse(a);
    }
    if(b.contains('K')){
      b = b.replaceAll('K','');
      b = double.parse(b) * 1000;
    }else{
      b = double.parse(b);
    }
    return a.compareTo(b);
  });
  print(listData);
```